# How to fix the table and make it nicer?

Tags: tables, tabularx

I have a table using the following code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{booktabs}% http://ctan.org/pkg/booktabs
\newcommand{\tabitem}{~~\llap{\textbullet}~~}
\setlength{\arrayrulewidth}{0.15mm}
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{18pt}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{0.2}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{ragged2e} % <---
\usepackage{lineno}
\usepackage{tabularx} % <---
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\graphicspath{ {images/} }
\usepackage[font=normalsize,labelfont=bf]{caption}
\captionsetup{justification=raggedright, singlelinecheck=false }

\usepackage{enumitem, etoolbox}
\AtBeginEnvironment{table}{\setlist[itemize, 1]{wide=0pt, leftmargin= *, topsep=0pt, itemsep=0pt, labelsep=.333em,
before=\leavevmode\vspace*{-\baselineskip},after= \vspace*{-\baselineskip}}}

\newcolumntype{I}{ >{\itemize}X<{\enditemize}}

\usepackage{makecell}
\renewcommand\theadfont{\normalsize\bfseries}

\usepackage{xcolor}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[!htb]
  \centering%
  \setlength{\tabcolsep}{1pt}
  \caption{Title}
  \tiny
  \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{@{}l>{\RaggedRight}X>{\RaggedRight}X%
    >{\RaggedRight}I}% The target layout does not centre the text so we don't want \centering
    \toprule% nicer rules courtesy of booktabs - but then we need to drop the verticals
      & \thead{Vulnerabilities} & \thead{Solution} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\bfseries Comment}%
    \tabularnewline\midrule%
    \textbf{1} &Secrets are managed and deployed by k8s and runtime&
    Offload the secret management and deployment to secret manager and the shield
    
    % \begin{itemize}
    % \item I would like this text to be bulleted with ragged right. I would also like this text to be bulleted with ragged right.
    % \item I would also like this text to be bulleted with ragged right.
    % \item I would also like this text to be bulleted with ragged right.
    % \end{itemize}
    &
    \item Vulnerability resolved.
    \item A demo can be found in section 3.

    % \item I would also like this text to be bulleted with ragged right.
    % \item I would also like this text to be bulleted with ragged right.
    \tabularnewline
    \addlinespace\midrule%
    \textbf{2} &EXEC operation
    \begin{enumerate}[label=(\alph*)]
        \item Missing authentication and access control
        \item Commands are transmitted by untrusted runtime 
    \end{enumerate}
    & Add EXEC checker in Qkernel and cryptographic protection for privileged commands

    
    &  
    \item Vulnerability resolved.
    \item A demo can be found in section 3.


    
    \tabularnewline
    \addlinespace\midrule%
    \textbf{3} & Lack of protection for STDIO of process
    & Add STDIO shield in Qkernel
    &  
    \item STDIO shield only encrypts STDOUT and STDERR (Demo in Section 3)
    \item Protection for STDIO of interactive process (i.e., terminal) is out of the scope 
    \tabularnewline

        \addlinespace\midrule%
    \textbf{4(a)} & Lack of protection for data written to volume
    & Add filesystem shield (Section 3)
    &  
    \item Out of the scope
    \tabularnewline

    \addlinespace\midrule%
    \textbf{4(b)} & Loading compromised binary and share library
    & Add software measurement manager in Qkernel (Section 3)
    &  
    \item Vulnerability resolved
    \item Demo can be found in section 3 and 3.
    \tabularnewline


    

  
    
    \bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
\end{table}


\end{document}
```

And I got the table in the picture:
[image]

Proleme 1: how to make `comment` as big as `solution`

Proleme 2: How to make list aligned with the `EXEC OPERATION`

Any idea of how to fix the table and make it nicer?

Problem 3: As you can see from the figure 2， the two columns are too close together. Do you know how to adjust the distance between them?

**Figure 2:**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

My main recommendation would be not to use `\tiny`. Instead, load the `rotating` package and place the `tabularx` environment in a `sidewaystable` environment, where the table will be rendered in landscape format.

To alleviate the narrowness of the intercolumn gaps, get rid of the `\setlength\tabcolsep{1pt}` directive that occurs right before `\caption{Title}`. While you're at it, get rid of the earlier instruction, `\setlength{\tabcolsep}{18pt}` as well. (The default value for this parameter, for the `article` and many other document classes, is `6pt`.)

And to give the table an even more open and inviting "look", I'd next replace the interior `\midrule` directives with `\addlinespace` directives.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs,ragged2e,tabularx,rotating}
\newcolumntype{L}{>{\RaggedRight}X}

\usepackage{caption}
\captionsetup{%
     justification=raggedright, 
     singlelinecheck=false,
     labelfont=bf, % is this really needed?
     skip=0.5\baselineskip}

\usepackage{enumitem} % for \newlist and \setlist macros
% Define compact forms of 'itemize' and 'enumerate' 
% environments, for use in tables:
\newlist{tabitemize}{itemize}{1}
\setlist[tabitemize,1]{%
     label= \textbullet, left=0pt, nosep, 
     before=\begin{minipage}[t]{\hsize},
     after= \end{minipage}}
\newlist{tabenumerate}{enumerate}{1}
\setlist[tabenumerate,1]{%
     label=(\alph*), left=0pt, nosep, align=left,
     before=\begin{minipage}[t]{\hsize},
     after= \end{minipage}}

\begin{document}

\begin{sidewaystable}
\caption{Title}

\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{@{} l LLL @{}}
    \toprule 
    & Vulnerabilities & Solution & Comment \\
    \midrule
    \textbf{1} 
    & Secrets are managed and deployed by k8s and runtime
    & Offload the secret management and deployment to secret manager and the shield
    &
    \begin{tabitemize}
    \item Vulnerability resolved.
    \item A demo can be found in section 3.
    \end{tabitemize} \\
    \addlinespace
    \textbf{2}
    & EXEC operation
      \begin{tabenumerate}
        \item Missing authentication and access control
        \item Commands are transmitted by untrusted runtime
      \end{tabenumerate}
    & Add EXEC checker in Qkernel and cryptographic protection for privileged commands
    &
    \begin{tabitemize}
    \item Vulnerability resolved.
    \item A demo can be found in section~3.
    \end{tabitemize} \\
    \addlinespace
    \textbf{3}
    & Lack of protection for STDIO of process
    & Add STDIO shield in Qkernel
    &
    \begin{tabitemize}
    \item STDIO shield only encrypts STDOUT and STDERR (Demo in Section~3)
    \item Protection for STDIO of interactive process (i.e., terminal) is out of the scope
    \end{tabitemize} \\
    \addlinespace
    \textbf{4(a)}
    & Lack of protection for data written to volume
    & Add filesystem shield (Section~3)
    &
    \begin{tabitemize}
    \item Out of the scope
    \end{tabitemize} \\
    \addlinespace
    \textbf{4(b)}
    & Loading compromised binary and share library
    & Add software measurement manager in Qkernel (Section~3)
    &
    \begin{tabitemize}
    \item Vulnerability resolved
    \item Demo can be found in section 3 and 3.
    \end{tabitemize} \\
    \bottomrule
\end{tabularx}

\end{sidewaystable}

\end{document}
```